# Flask app перестает отвечать на запросы после 10-15 перезагрузок страницы с видео стримингом

Tags: многопоточность, flask, tensorflow

Пишу приложение, которое должно стримить изображение с камеры внутри сети. в скрипте используется tensorflow для детекта лиц на изображении.

В качестве основы был взят этот пример:
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask

Столкнулся с проблемой. После 10-15 перезагрузок страницы на которую стримится видео, приложение зависает и перестает отвечать на запросы.

Код потока обрабатывающего видео с камеры:

```py
def detect_emotion():
    global vs, outputFrame, tracker
    global faces, gray, tracker_initiated
    global emotions

    fps = FPS().start()
    CURRENT_FPS = 0
    frame_ind = 0

    scale_x = cfg.SCALE_WIDTH
    scale_y = cfg.SCALE_HEIGHT

    while True:
        time.sleep(0.01)
        try:
            out_frame = vs.read()
            out_frame = cv2.resize(out_frame, (cfg.OUT_WIDTH, cfg.OUT_HEIGHT))

            with lock:
                gray = cv2.resize(out_frame, (cfg.IN_WIDTH, cfg.IN_HEIGHT))
                gray = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            if tracker_initiated:
                with lock:
                    success, box = tracker.update(gray)

                if success:
                    x, y, w, h = [int(i) for i in box]

                    x = 0 if x < 0 else (cfg.IN_WIDTH-1 if x > cfg.IN_WIDTH-1 else x)
                    y = 0 if y < 0 else (cfg.IN_HEIGHT-1 if y > cfg.IN_HEIGHT-1 else y)

                    with lock:
                        roi = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]

                    roi = cv2.resize(roi, input_shape, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
                    roi = roi.astype("float") / 255.0
                    roi = img_to_array(roi)
                    roi = np.expand_dims(roi, axis=0)
                    preds = emotion_classifier.predict(roi)[0]

                    with lock:
                        emotions = [int(emotion*100) for emotion in preds]

                    emotion = np.argmax(preds)

                    x, y, w, h = (x//scale_x, y//scale_y, w//scale_x, h//scale_y)
                    x, y, w, h = (int(x), int(y), int(w), int(h))

                    draw_border(out_frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), cfg.SELECTED_COLOR, 3, 5, 30)

                    out_frame = Image.fromarray(out_frame)
                    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(out_frame)

                    tW, tH = font.getsize(cfg.EMOTIONS_RUS[emotion])
                    draw.rectangle(((x-2, y+h+5), (x+tW+2, y+h+tH+2)), fill = cfg.SELECTED_COLOR)
                    draw.text((x, y+h),  cfg.EMOTIONS_RUS[emotion], font = font, fill = (255, 255, 255, 255))

                    out_frame = np.array(out_frame)
                else:
                    reset_face()
            else:
                with lock:
                    faces = face_detector.detectMultiScale(gray)

                    for x, y, w, h in faces:
                        x, y, w, h = (x//scale_x, y//scale_y, w//scale_x, h//scale_y)
                        x, y, w, h = (int(x), int(y), int(w), int(h))

                        draw_border(out_frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), cfg.NOT_SELECTED_COLOR, 3, 5, 30)

            #Draw fps
            draw_text_w_background(out_frame, 'FPS: %.2f' % CURRENT_FPS,
                (20, 20),
                cfg.font, cfg.fontScale,
                cfg.fontColor, cfg.bgColor, 1)

            fps.update()

            if (frame_ind == 10):
                fps.stop()

                CURRENT_FPS = fps.fps()
                fps = FPS().start()
                frame_ind = 0

            # cv2.circle(gray, , 1, (255, 255, 0), -1)
            with lock:
                outputFrame = out_frame.copy()

            frame_ind += 1
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            continue
```

Код генератора стрима:

```py
def generate():
    global outputFrame

    while True:
        with lock:
            if outputFrame is None:
                continue

            (flag, encodedImage) = cv2.imencode(".jpg", outputFrame)

        if not flag:
            continue

        yield(b'--frame\r\n' 
            b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + bytearray(encodedImage) + b'\r\n')
```

route:

```py
@app.route("/video_feed")
def video_feed():
    return Response(generate(), 
        mimetype = "multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame")
```

Запуск приложения:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = threading.Thread(target=detect_emotion)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

    app.run('0.0.0.0', '80', debug=True, 
        threaded=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в generate(), после того, как клиент отключался, стрим не переставал генерироваться.
Решение: ловить ошибку GeneratorExit и прерывать стрим.

Обновленная generate():

```py
def generate():
    global outputFrame

    try:
        while True:
            with lock:
                if outputFrame is None:
                    continue

                (flag, encodedImage) = cv2.imencode(".jpg", outputFrame)

            if not flag:
                continue

            yield(b'--frame\r\n' 
                b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + bytearray(encodedImage) + b'\r\n')

    except GeneratorExit:
        return '1'
```